# Multimethod for Proxy

Tags: raku

Is it possible to use multidispatch for the store method when using a Proxy?  In the following minimal example, the code is called when storing an `Int`

```
my $foo := do {
  my $bar = 1;
  Proxy.new:
    :FETCH( method { return $bar} ),
    :STORE( method (Int $i) { $bar = $i } )
}

say $foo;   # 1
$foo = 2;
say $foo;   # 2
$foo = "3"; # error, need to pass an Int
```

But I'd like to handle the `STORE` differently if given, say, a `Str`.  The work around I've found (other than doing a mega method with `given`/`where` is to create a `multi sub` inside of a block, and return the sub (because a `multi method` can't be referred to with `&foo`) with an dummy first parameter:

```
my $foo := do {
  my $bar = 1;
  Proxy.new:
    :FETCH( method { return $bar} ),
    :STORE( 
      do { 
        multi sub xyzzy ($, Int $i) { $bar = $i }
        multi sub xyzzy ($, Str $i) { $bar = +$i + 1}
        &xyzzy
      }
    )
}

say $foo;   # 1
$foo = 2;   
say $foo;   # 2
$foo = "3"; 
say $foo;   # 4
```

Is there a better way to do this (mainly for code clarity using `method` because `sub` feels...misleading)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With regards to being misleading: the `FETCH` and `STORE` values expecte `Callables`, which could be either a `method` or a `sub`.

Getting back to the question, there is no direct way of doing this, but there is a better indirect way that may be clearer.  You can do this by setting up the `multi sub` first, and then passing the `proto` as the parameter:

```
proto sub store(|) {*}
multi sub store(\self, Int) { say "Int" }
multi sub store(\self, Str) { say "Str" }

my $a := Proxy.new(
  FETCH => -> $ { 42 },
  STORE => &store,
);

say $a;     # 42
$a = 42;    # Int
$a = "foo"; # Str
```

And if you want to make the code shorter, but possibly less understandable, you can get rid of the `proto` (because it will be auto-generated for you) and the `sub` in the `multi` (because you can):

```
multi store(\self, Int) { say "Int" }
multi store(\self, Str) { say "Str" }

my $a := Proxy.new(
  FETCH => -> $ { 42 },
  STORE => &store,
);

say $a;     # 42
$a = 42;    # Int
$a = "foo"; # Str
```

Comment: I only meant misleading in the sense that I'm passing a `sub` which is clearly being used as a `method` (and thus the need for the dummy `$` in the signature), because I couldn't make a `multi method` and then pass it.  But your point of doing `\self` for the first parameter actually would help clarify to future code readers the intent of the `sub`

Comment: FWIW, even if they were methods, the `self` would be useless inside, as `self` is always decontainerized.  Which would mean it would do a `FETCH` on itself.